# getselecteddataasync() not working in outlook read mode in outlook addin

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

How can I select a text in reading mode in outlook to be used by an add-in? 
In compose mode, I used getselecteddataasync() API for getting the selected text.However, this API has a limitation that it does not work in read mode.
Looking for a similar one in read mode.

Other option could be to use the body API as referenced here:
 https://dev.outlook.com/reference/addins/1.1/Office.context.mailbox.item.html#bod
y
Using this, whole body will be selected. I can use regEx and hashTags but that is not what i want. I want to know what text has been selected in reading mode.
I am using HTML and JS for coding this addin.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have another option then playing with regEx and hashTags on the string you get from :

```
     Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync
```

Look here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b51a8873-ce77-418c-bd27-e2f29b277e4d/itemgetselecteddataasync-is-undefined-doesnt-exist-mail-apps?forum=appsforoffice

This outlook add in API limited in many things...

Good Luck